# 2sxc File upload error NULL

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke

Running into problems on one dnn8 (8.04) installation where the file upload does not work correctly. The file uploads, then when using in app it says "Upload failed because: null" and when using in content it says: "Upload failed because: Die Laufzeitbindung kann für einen NULL-Verweis nicht ausgeführt werden".

I have tried updating 2SXC from version 9.4. all the way up to 9.23 but the problem persists, so I am guessing it is not a module problem.

Any idea what the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as Admin or host when you get this error?

Comment: I'm logged in as Host.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. There was a way too large number set in DNN for Max File Upload. Not idea how that got in there. The module update to 2SXC 9.30 was the solution because this gave more detailed error messages than the previous versions.